# Storm analog for spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-storm

There is `spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition` property in Spark Streaming, which limits number of messages reading from Apache Kafka per second. Is there similar property for Storm?

Comment: What version of storm do you have ?

Comment: @fhuz, version 1.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no property to limit  the number of messages per second.

If you use the [new kafka client](https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/external/storm-kafka-client) (kafka 0.9) spout you can set '`MaxUncommittedOffsets`' that will throttle the number of uncommited offsets(i.e number of inflight messages).

However, if you are still using the old kafka spout(kafka prior to 0.9), you can use the storm property `'topology.max.spout.pending'` which throttles the total number of unacknowledged messages per spout task.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround, which helps to do that in Storm. You can simply write following wrapper for KafkaSpout, which count number of messages emitted by spout per second. When it reaches desired number (`Config.RATE`) it returns nothing.

```
public class MyKafkaSpout extends KafkaSpout {
    private int counter = 0;
    private int currentSecond = 0;
    private final int tuplesPerSecond = Config.RATE;

    public MyKafkaSpout(SpoutConfig spoutConf) {
        super(spoutConf);
    }

    @Override
    public void nextTuple() {
        if (counter == tuplesPerSecond) {
            int newSecond = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis());
            if (newSecond <= currentSecond) {
                return;
            }
            counter = 0;
            currentSecond = newSecond;
        }

        ++counter;
        super.nextTuple();
    }
}
```